# Joining two tables/views with different columns Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

My Oracle SQL skills is not that good. I want to join two tables/views with different columns as one. I want the output of query 2 to be joined with the output of query1 e.g.

```
--**Query 1**:

select INSTANCE_NAME AS DATABASE_NAME, HOST_NAME, VERSION_FULL AS DATABASE_VERSION, EDITION AS DATABASE_EDITION from v$instance

[enter image description here][1]

--**Query 2**:
SELECT VERSION_NO AS APEX_VERSION, API_COMPATIBILITY AS APEX_API_COMPATIBILITY, PATCH_APPLIED AS APEX_PATCH_APPLIED FROM APEX_RELEASE

[enter image description here][1]
```

**Desired Output**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxnbR.png)
[image: 3]

Comment: you need to provide sample data and desired output

Comment: I have added the sampled data and desired output

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know that these tables return a single row you can just create a Cartesian product, i.e. a query without any joins like this:

```
select i.instance_name as database_name, i.host_name, i.version_full as database_version, i.edition as database_edition, r.version_no as apex_version, r.api_compatibility as apex_api_compatibility, r.patch_applied as apex_patch_applied
from   v$instance i, apex_release r
```

Comment: Why don't you accept/upvote the answer, then, @Sean?